# Reading TCP/IP datastream with Westhold's Race Manager software

Tags: vb.net, tcp

I am working on an application that uploads timing results of an auto race to an online website. Currently, it uses XML files. There is also a data stream option where what's called an RMonitor protocol (documentation here: http://www.imsatiming.com/software/protocols/AMB%20RMonitor%20Timing%20Protocol.pdf) is streamed over an IP port. This provides more information that I would like to get and put into databases online so the user can get more data.

I have not had any success in trying to read the data that is streamed over this network. I am programming in Visual Basic. I have downloaded two simple projects - one for a TCP/IP chat program and the other a UDP listener program. When I try to connect to the IP address and port no data is shown in the output window.

The software that I'm trying to connect to creates a server and then (I assume) sends the data through that connection. Do I need to send something to initiate the feed maybe?

The software (Race Manager) that I'm trying to connect to can be downloaded here: http://westhold.com/download.html

I am new to programming TCP/IP connections and am interested in learning. I'm just asking for pointers and help along the way to finding out how to connect to this "server connection." Once I get connected and the data stream flowing, I can program everything to get it working with databases. It's just getting to read the data where I'm struggling. I included RMonitor and the Race Manager download links for anyone to see if they can get the data when I could not. (There is a demo mode that allows for a race to be ran)

I would really appreciate help with this. If needed I can try asking the creator of the Race Manager software, but don't know how much help he would be (if he would help me with my own software). I figured stackoverflow would be better due to all the experience others may have. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: `I have not had any success in trying to read the data that is streamed over this network`, please show us what you have tried and what is not working. As of right now it's all guess work.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I have tried using ip addresses 127.0.0.1 and the ip address of my computer along with the correct port as indicated in the Race Manager software. I have tried this using TCP/IP chat https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/TCP-Communication-in-VBNET-f6c48ca0 and UDP listener https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-UDP-Listener-352f8cde

Comment: Use as TCP Listener (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netframework-4.7.2) that should get you started